# How to open a pdf in android by pressing a button?

Tags: java, android, pdf

I'm creating an app to open a PDF application from a button, but what I did is not going well. 
In my layout there is only one button , which seeks want and open a PDF file.
Not giving error in Eclipse , just in tablet appears " readerPDF stopped ." 
I do not know what to do. somebody help me.

Sorry for my english.

```
public class ReaderActivity extends Activity {

    private Button btnOpen;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_reader);

        btnOpen.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                String filename = null;
                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +"/"+ filename);
                Intent target = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                target.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),"application/pdf");
                target.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);

                Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(target, "Open File");
                try {
                    startActivity(intent);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

                } 
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

`filename` is `null`, so the path you are passing to the third-party app does not point to a PDF file.

Comment: then how should I initialize the filename ? If I get the null, gives error

Comment: @MaylaCampos: Nobody, other than perhaps you, has any idea where your PDF is. You are the one who is trying to create an app to open a PDF. It is your job, as a programmer, to know where the PDF is. We cannot readily help you with that. For lightweight testing, copy a PDF to your phone, then create a `File` object pointing to where you placed the PDF.

Comment: I know in the case just do not know where to put. The file is named test and that the sdcard. I put String filename = "sdcard / test.pdf"
or
  File file = new File (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory () getAbsolutePath () + "/" + sdcard / test.pdf.);

Comment: @MaylaCampos: I do not know what you consider "the sdcard" to mean. If you truly mean [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html), you do not have access to that. If you mean [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), then probably get rid of `sdcard/` in your code from your previous comment. `getExternalStorageDirectory()` points to the root of external storage, so if `test.pdf` in is in the root of external storage, you do not need `sdcard/` in your code.